# How to mail the exact file content through Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I want to mail the below file through Jenkins(include newlines).

**$ cat summary.txt**

---|   My First test   |---

Total Tests: 1

Total Passes: 0

Total Errors: 0

Total Failures: 1

Total Skipped tests: 0

**Jenkins job configuration:**

**Inject environment variables:**

***Properties File Path***
/path/summary.txt

**Editable Email Notification:**

***Default content:***
$DEFAULT_CONTENT
${FILE, path="summary.txt"}

**Received Mail:**

First - Build # 111 - Still Failing: Check console output at http://1.1.1.1:8080/job/First/11/ to view the results. ---| My First test |--- Total Tests: 1 Total Passes: Total Errors: 0 Total Failures: 1 Total Skipped tests:

**Expected Mail:**

First - Build # 111 - Still Failing: Check console output at http://1.1.1.1:8080/job/First/111/ to view the results.

---|   My First test   |---

Total Tests: 1

Total Passes: 0

Total Errors: 0

Total Failures: 1

Total Skipped tests: 0

Comment: are you using email external plugin or you are sending mail through what?

Comment: Using Email-ext plugin.

Comment: instead of doing like that, you can attach the build log to the email. Because sometimes log may be of too much size.

Comment: Yes, this(build_log) would be more helpful. Thanks :-)

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: Yep, For time being I can use it.

My build log contains around 500+ test cases results.So my team lead wants me to send only test cases status details(the one I mentioned above) to him.

Comment: I've put the same as answer. For everyone. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your build log is too long, putting all the content in the body might not be good and cumbersome too. So instead of that, please make it as an attachment to the email. So that Long content, format issues etc issues will be gone. You can do that in the script by `this(build_log)` calling this. Hope this is helps.

Comment: Thanks.Yes, you are right, I have modified the script as below.This helps to complete my task. Also, I referred this link (https://sathishpk.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/how-to-edit-email-notification-in-jenkins/comment-page-1/)

cp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/$BUILD_ID/log .
echo "tests=""Total Tests: $tests" >> summary.txt
echo "pass=""Total Passes: $total_passed_cases" >> summary.txt
echo "errors=""Total Errors: $errors" >> summary.txt
echo "failures=""Total Failures: $failures" >> summary.txt
Default Content:Test Cases Details:     $tests$pass$errors $failuresAttachments: log

Comment: Is my answer okay for you then?

Comment: Yes It's very useful for me :-)

Comment: Then please accept the answer. so that others will look into other posts. :)